# Headphones with dual jack, reduced volume

Tags: voltage, current, audio, basic, speakers

I recently built a pair of headphones and added an audio jack input to both the cans, for convenience of connecting.

That would also serve another purpose of letting my girlfriend hear the same music without me having to take off the headphone.

But the problem I noticed is that the volume gets reduced. Now this is primarily because its getting connected in parallel, so is there any way to subdue the problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The headphones are sharing the power output (P=IV) of your source. Therefore the volume halves when you do this.
The options you have are to either increase the output of your device. ie turn up the volume. Or add a powered amplifier inline to your headphones. Some models of headphones have these built in.